# Hide the border of the selected cell in qtablewidget in pyqt?

Tags: pyqt, qtablewidget

Is there a way i can hide the border of the selected cell(or make the border color as white)in a qtablewidget.. By default a border with dotted line is shown.. Can u help me...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like this dotted border around selected cell you're trying to hide is a focus rectangle. Any given cell can have focus and not be selected at the same time and vice-versa. If you want this border to not get painted use an item delegate. There you can remove State_HasFocus style from the item's state before painting it. Pls, see an example below on how to do this, it's c++, let me know if you have troubles converting it to python

```
// custom item delegate class
class NoFocusDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
protected:
    void paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index) const;
};

void NoFocusDelegate::paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QStyleOptionViewItem itemOption(option);
    if (itemOption.state & QStyle::State_HasFocus)
        itemOption.state = itemOption.state ^ QStyle::State_HasFocus;
    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, itemOption, index);
}
...
// set the item delegate to your table widget
ui->tableView->setItemDelegate(new NoFocusDelegate());
```

hope this helps, regards

Comment: Many thanks for replying.. I've achieved the same with setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus) since i've used qtablewidget.. I'm not familiar with delegates though.. I can't upvote this answer.. It says the reputation points must be greater than 15..

Answer (score 17):

I prefer to do:

```
ui->tableWidget->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);
```

You can also change the focus policy using the design tab.

Comment: .. but you lose  keyboard navigation feature by doing so

Answer (score 3):

`Qt::NoFocus` will remove the selected state of rows in `QTableWidget`.

The `Python3/PySide2` version to the accepted answer:

```
class NoFocusDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter: PySide2.QtGui.QPainter, option: PySide2.QtWidgets.QStyleOptionViewItem, index: PySide2.QtCore.QModelIndex) -> None:
        itemOption = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionViewItem(option)
        if option.state & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_HasFocus:
            itemOption.state = itemOption.state ^ QtWidgets.QStyle.State_HasFocus
        super().paint(painter, itemOption, index)

table.setItemDelegate(NoFocusDelegate())
```

Worked perfectly for me.