# Drawing a check mark in Qt

Tags: qt, user-interface, qtreeview, qtgui

I am working with simple QTreeView.  Each row of tree is a specific class inherited from one class **EditorRow**.

**EditorRow** has these functions:

```
virtual QVariant data(ColumnIndexEnum index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const = 0;
virtual void setData(const QVariant& data, ColumnIndexEnum index, int role = Qt::UserRole);
virtual QWidget* getEditor(QWidget* parent) const;
```

Each row has its specific widget, which is shown in the right column when selecting that row. When the row is not selected `data` function returns appropriate value for each row(f.e. the value which was chosen in the QComboBox).

But in case of row, which's widget is QCheckBox, I need to draw a checked(or unchecked) checkbox when the row is not selected.

I have tried to use Decoration role like this:

```
if(Qt::DecorationRole == role)
  {
    if(ValueColumn == index)
    {
      QStyle* style = QApplication::style();
      QStyleOptionButton opt;
      opt.state |= QStyle::State_Enabled;

      if(isChecked())
         opt.state = QStyle::State_On;
      else
         opt.state = QStyle::State_Off;


      const int indicatorWidth = style->pixelMetric(QStyle::PM_IndicatorWidth, &opt);
      const int indicatorHeight = style->pixelMetric(QStyle::PM_IndicatorHeight, &opt);
      const int listViewIconSize = indicatorWidth;
      const int pixmapWidth = indicatorWidth;
      const int pixmapHeight = qMax(indicatorHeight, listViewIconSize);

      opt.rect = QRect(0, 0, indicatorWidth, indicatorHeight);

      QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap(pixmapWidth, pixmapHeight);
      pixmap.fill(Qt::transparent);
      {
      QPainter painter(&pixmap);
      QCheckBox cb;
      cb.setLayoutDirection(Qt::RightToLeft);
      style->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_IndicatorCheckBox, &opt, &painter, &cb);
      }
      return QIcon(pixmap);
    }
}
```

It actually works, but the icon is shown always, even when the row is selected.
I think it is because of DecorationRole.

Do You have any ideas how to handle this problem ?

Thank You.

Comment: Why don't you use `Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable` flag for your chackable items? It will automatically draw the check box.

Comment: Could you provide a simple example of that usage. I couldn't find an example for using that flag.

Comment: In your model reimplement `QAbstractItemModel::flags(const QModelIndex &) const` function that should return `return Qt::ItemIsEditable | Qt::ItemIsEnabled | Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt::ItemIsSelectable;` for checkable nodes.

Comment: And don't forget to set default value: `model()->data( Qt::Unchecked, Qt::CheckStateRole );`

Comment: P.S. if you preffer custom drawing you may check this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/16301316/1035613